# Accessing the permissions of a file: st_mode an alternative of access()?

Tags: c

The permission bits can be ascertained using the `st_mode` field of the struct returned by the `stat()` function. How are they related to the `access()` function? I'm not sure I understand well, but `access()` does the same thing (you can check for the file permissions). Which is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat` is much more general and can return all sorts of information about a file. E.g. one might use `stat` to ascertain the owner of a file, or its last write time without ever being interested in accessing the file itself.

You can use the information returned by `stat` (as well as your own UID and GID) to check whether you're allowed to `open` a file. However this can be a bit involved, and so `access` can be a convenience.

That said, using `access` is a bit of a code smell. Unless you simply wish to know whether you *can* access a file *right now*, but do not intend to then actually open the file, you should not use `access`. Race conditions are a big problem for secure programs, and thus when working with I/O you should simply `open` away and handle the error afterwards. Calling `access` and then assuming an `open` is okay is simply asking for problems.

Comment: thanks! Could you also give me a short answer of how exactly is this still valabile in Windows?

Comment: @Cătălina Sîrbu I don't think Windows is relevant for this question.

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu, there is no reason to remove it.  It has its uses.  Also, even if it was no longer useful, it can't be removed, because that would break existing programs that call it.

Comment: @orlp, I can see some uses of `access` where the race condition would not be a factor.  For example, you may use it to decide if certain UI elements should be disabled.

Comment: But related to the fact that the way windows works is different from *nix and therefore things like `st_nlink` or `st_mode` are not available in Win

Comment: @JoelFan Sure, but I already included that in my answer. In that scenario you do not intend to call `open` afterwards and assume it's okay.

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu, are you sure?  I'm pretty sure all POSIX functions are available in Windows.  They may not return what you expect but they are still available.

Comment: @JoelFan it is a thing hard for me to explain how I can run on windows posix functions, but yes,they are available and I don't understand if it is a mistake or is just me who doesn't understand how platforms and compilers works :)

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu, the idea of POSIX is that all the functions should be available on all platforms that support POSIX, e.g. Windows.  Due to platform limitations, the functions may not perform the same on all platforms, but they still need to be available and perform as best they can for each platform.  The goal of POSIX is not to completely eliminate platform differences but rather to minimize them.

Comment: @JoelFan it is not about "availability of API-functions"; it is about the semantics of the underlying file system. In unix, all file system operations are ATOMIC. Period. In windows: it depends on the FS and the phase of the moon. (like NFS used to be ~30 years ago)

Comment: @wildplasser from the POSIX FAQ: "The POSIX.1 standard specifies application programming interfaces (APIs) at the source level, and is about source code portability"

Comment: @JoelFan: so you end up with the same set of functions, doing different things on different platforms. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The `access` function returns a boolean (as an `int`) value just to tell you if your "real" userid would have the type of access that you pass to the `access` function.  You must pass the type of access you are checking for to the `access` function. It does all the access computation for you.

`st_mode` just gives you the raw permission bits on the file.  You don't have to tell it what kind of access you want to check.  You have to interpret the bits yourself.